# Can employees please provide some indication that a lower-priority request is being looked into or has been internally reported?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, stack-exchange-team

This is not a duplicate of [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange). That specifically refers to high-profile requests that receive a lot of votes, and the answer there addresses that specifically. This, on the other hand, is for more minor things that don't receive lots of votes and views, that the SE team deems of low priority. Additionally, the "response" there refers to a decision and a status tag; this, on the other hand, refers to something to the effect of "we're looking into/discussing this and will make a decision regarding status".

Sometimes, when people post a bug report or feature request here on meta, the SE team decides it's of lower priority, and decides not to respond to it for the time being. More than likely, they place it onto their internal issue tracker and possibly give it a "low" priority.

But from the outset, it **appears that such requests are being completely ignored**. I'm willing to make the good-faith assumption that each of these requests is in fact being looked at by an employee, who decided not to take action at that time.

Ideally, it would be great if SE opened up their internal issue tracker to the public, to see what priorities the team has assigned to every request, but I can see some issues with that (e.g. "why is my *important* issue low priority?").

I think it would be great for SE's relations with the community if they at least, for example, commented on each request that gets logged in their internal issue tracker with a comment to the effect of "we're aware of this issue and are looking into it". This way, it's clear to everyone that SE is listening to people on meta. This was an important point in [Monica Cellio's Medium post](https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f), which said that despite all the internal chat that surrounds an event, it makes it seem like no action is being taken:

> I know through internal channels that you’re thinking about how to respond more to all this. But internal channels do nothing for the public record.

Yes, I'm aware that sometimes employees are busy handling things, but a simple comment to this effect takes very little time.

Comment: I know how you feel. But given Tim’s recent answer on the related question, I think it’s best if we forebear a bit on asking for such follow-ups. He’s laid out a plan. They’re dealing fairly with us. Let’s give them some space to breathe. Just as we can feel pressured by the SE employees, and it can exasperate and exhaust us, it works the other direction too.

Comment: Like a "product life-cycle" of bugs and requests. One that indicates that your post is (for example) "being analyzed", or "standby", or "in progress"...

Comment: This made me wonder, how is "low priority" different form the status-deferred mod tag? Could this perceived ignoring be mitigated by making sure all bugs and requests get a proper stats-X tag?

Comment: "*Yes, I'm aware that sometimes employees are busy handling things, but a simple comment to this effect takes very little time.*" A single comment takes very little time. A *thousand* comments takes a lot longer. And what would the comment actually say? "We've seen this and may deal with it at some point in the future?" What's the point of that?

Comment: @rene This is not a duplicate. Please see the edit.

Comment: The outcome is the same.

Comment: @rene Not the same outcome. That post refers to a status tag (e.g. completed, declined, etc.) while this post refers to a comment to the effect of "we're looking into this and will make a decision regarding the right status tag".

Comment: Sure, let's not tie up SE staff in useless actions that only open them up to be harassed forever about why their *looking into it* didn't had any noticeable effect. This doesn't need to answered, the  arguments exchanged on the dupe apply here as well.

Comment: I like this idea. It sounds sort of like how issues can be tagged with low and high priorities on GitHub. Just adding that tag would definitely be enough to show that it has been noticed. Having a tag for priority also solves the problem Nicol brought up, because they don't have to leave a comment with "we'll think about it," they can just do a quick edit to add the tag.

Answer (score 7):

I guess *low priority* is an essential thing here.

If SE opened up the internal issue tracker, I can see it as a *constant source of distraction* - folks going "What about *my* ticket/post". I know a few users often ask about their support tickets, and a few *kinda* are a pain about it. The latter sort will be camped out there.

SE *isn't* an open source project, even in its heyday.

*Practically*, if they hired someone whose only job was to do this, and rubber stamp every single feature request that didn't fit into the road map, it would still slow things down as they checked. SE's pretty tight on staff right now.

TBH, I think a lot of this can be answered in Tim Post's post - [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317011/what-are-the-effective-communication-channels-for-effecting-change-to-se/317221#317221). I'm was tempted to cherry pick a few bits from it in supporting my answer, but you probably need to read it all in spite of that (Sorry!).

In short, though, it's hard enough for SE to keep us abreast of *major* changes, let alone the back end. I've learned a lot more from following a few key folks on Twitter than Meta sometimes.

To quote Tim:

> Meta doesn't track bugs well, it doesn't track feature requests well, it doesn't indicate presence from us well (how do you know what stuff Joe Friend has been looking at recently for distant scheduling?) and quite frankly, even working 60+ hour weeks, there's still not enough time to get everything done so adding even more writing on top of the PMs list of things to do isn't going to help.

So, meta is going to suck for this.

> I think, in 2019, we're going to have to bite the bullet and replace at least bug tracking and feature requests with something else, or have something else behind the pipeline consuming meta and making sure it gets put somewhere else in ordered form so we can work from it. I don't know what that's going to look like, I just know what we've got isn't working, and breaks even more embarrassingly by the week.

There might be something in the future, but it's something they need to work out. That said, I don't think minor feature requests would be a priority here, and I don't think it will be a classic issue tracker.

I've always found that effecting change on meta is just a little political - it's about aligning our goals and theirs, getting buy in for an idea, and that's something hard to do for 'minor issues'. It's not like the old days when a dev could go "eh, I can fix this in 10 minutes" and went and did it.

The best solution for pluralisation bugs for example, might be to mail users a sheet of appropriately sized S stickers...

Comment: This isn't about getting requests implemented, it's about the staff's *impression* and how they come off. If they don't comment on a minor feature request, it comes off as if they *completely ignored* it (even though there are [x] internal posts about it). There's nothing wrong with considering an issue as low priority; it's just that it comes across as ignorance. The second quote you mention makes a lot of sense, as it would no longer force users to take rep hits for requests that just happen to be unpopular.

Comment: I mean, literally - they might not have the time to comment, vote or answer on minor feature requests.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek "We don't have the time" - is not the best argument, you know. Especially when you have been hearing it for years =/

Comment: Well, true. But if its something that's clearly minor... and ya, we don't have time is a terrible arguement but ironically... that may take time to sort out a happy medium