# Why do you need to add a bounty to get attention on Stack Exchange Meta?

Tags: discussion, bounties, meta

When you post a question here you already spend time on it, formatting and wording it correctly, backup up everything with quotations and research.

But when you post a bug or feature request if you want it to be looked at you practically need to add a bounty. I added a bounty to my question six days ago and nobody has replied.

If you are making suggestions that will help a whole lot of people you should at least get a reply from an official source/moderator without having to pay reputation for it.

Basically you’re writing something that doesn’t really benefit you and you need to pay so people actually see it.

I don’t get it?

Comment: Uh...I doubt a bounty really gets you more attention from the necessary people either anyway. So, you don't really need to add a bounty at all, it's a game of luck and patience either way.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317271/can-employees-please-comment-on-lower-priority-requests-indicating-that-theyre

Comment: This is only my suspicion, and someone from SE would have to confirm it, but I doubt that bounties on Meta feature requests or bug notifications have a huge impact on whether someone responds (unless there's demonstrated support from the rest of the community). The rep reward basically doesn't matter to an employee - that's not why they're answering it - and the only symbolic meaning offering a bounty could have would be "Hey, this user thinks [X] is important." But whether an employee visibly acts would likely be based on the desires of the *community* or the *company* - not a single user.

Comment: That said, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211156/274942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128818/274942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180063/274942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397/274942, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56010/274942 (and links therein) for more information on the subject

Comment: @HDE226868 all of those posts are from the before times...(before SE got big) - currently the best, or at least most honest advice, seems to be [meta's broken use email, Twitter, and other channels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317011/what-are-the-effective-communication-channels-for-effecting-change-to-se/317221#317221). Pointing to the fact that featuring (bounty level featuring at least) is not really worth anything with Employees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think of bounties are pure transference of reputation... it's meaningless.

One of the purposes of bounties is to *get attention*. Some users spend bounties to try to bring attention to a pet cause they feel is neglected. Others actually want to bring attention and reward a great answer.

There's no guaranteed way to get an official answer - a few people insist on them, but frankly, it's probably not possible *all the time* and a lot of authoritative answers come from *users* simply because SE's got a lot of quirks that are more community than platform based.

That said, I'm pretty sure folks *read* meta and stuff probably gets discussed at some point. I've had feature requests get fulfilled significant periods of time after asking, with no real feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add bounty at all. You may have just suffered from posting at Christmas time when people are actually away doing other things, like attending time with family.

And yes, even SE staff take some time off during holidays, although I keep seeing Catija popping in...

Comment: Shhhh.... don't tell anyone!

Comment: You're terrible at taking time off @Catija

Answer (score 0):

If there was no requirement to bring attention to answers, it would become meaningless and there would be lots of questions with unnecessary attention. Requiring the user to give up some of their reputation makes sure they actually care about drawing attention to the question.

Usually bounties are used to reward an existing answer or give the question more attention. The bounty adds an incentive for users to look into the question more.